# what will be the output and how to get only object name in output

Tags: object-detection-api, yolov8

results = model.predict(source= path , show = True)

only detected name should display in terminal, instead of all atributes of results.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("runs/detect/train2/weights/best.pt")
path = 'row_photos'
results = model.predict(source= path , show = True)
```